# Read multi line rows into a single row using python or python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data like this:

```
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16077: POWER     ID|7817|I|103306|||D|1
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16011: BINGHAM   ID|45607|I|103306|||D|1
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16005: BANNOCK   ID|82839|I|103306|||D|1
MP|3561250|||WQTI576        
|BEA135|48301: LOVING    TX|82|I|103308|||D|1
MP|3561250|||WQTI576        
|BEA135|48443: TERRELL   TX|984|I|103308|||D|1
MP|3561250|||WQTI576        
|BEA135|48173: GLASSCOCK     TX|1226|I|103308|||D|1
```

How do i achieve this:

```
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16077: POWER     ID|7817|I|103306|||D|1
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16011: BINGHAM   ID|45607|I|103306|||D|1
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16005: BANNOCK   ID|82839|I|103306|||D|1
MP|3561250|||WQTI575|BEA135|48301: LOVING    TX|82|I|103308|||D|1
MP|3561250|||WQTI576|BEA135|48443: TERRELL   TX|984|I|103308|||D|1
MP|3561250|||WQTI576|BEA135|48173: GLASSCOCK TX|1226|I|103308|||D|1
```

I tried this:

```
f=open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/a.csv','r')
lines=f.readlines()
mystr = '|'.join([line.strip() for line in lines])
print(mystr)
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16077: POWER, 
ID|7817|I|103306|||D|1|MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16011: BINGHAM, 
ID|45607|I|103306|||D|1|MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16005: BANNOCK, 
ID|82839|I|103306|||D|1|MP|3561250|||WQTI576|||BEA135|48301: LOVING, 
TX|82|I|103308|||D|1|MP|3561250|||WQTI576|||BEA135|48443: TERRELL, 
TX|984|I|103308|||D|1|MP|3561250|||WQTI576|||BEA135|48173: GLASSCOCK, 
TX|1226|I|103308|||D|1|MP|3561250|||WQTI576|
```

I am not achieving the way i want, any help please? The first column always had a data of MP, and each row has 13 pipes as delimiters.

Edited:

How to do the same thing with the finding 'MP' instead of 'D|1', below is what i tried, but not giving the right thing cuz there are some rows that doesn't have the 'D|1' and has 'U|1234' something like that at the end

```
content = ([l.strip().decode('utf-8') for l in s1 if l.strip()])

for line in content:
    find_START = line.find('MP')   # check if line has D|1
    if find_START ==0:
       tmp += line
       res.append(tmp)
       tmp = ''
    else:
     tmp += line

for r in res:
    print(r)
```

Its printing as below:

```
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16011: BINGHAM, ID|45607|I|103306|||D|1
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16005: BANNOCK, ID|82839|I|103306|||D|1
MP|3561250|||WQTI576
|BEA135|48301: LOVING, TX|82|I|103308|||D|1MP|3561250|||WQTI576
|BEA135|48443: TERRELL, TX|984|I|103308|||D|1MP|3561250|||WQTI576
|BEA135|48173: GLASSCOCK, TX|1226|I|103308|||D|1MP|3561250|||WQTI576
```

Comment: each line should be ending with `D|1`, not that hard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**logFile**:

```
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16077: POWER     ID|7817|I|103306|||D|1
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16011: BINGHAM   ID|45607|I|103306|||D|1
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16005: BANNOCK   ID|82839|I|103306|||D|1
MP|3561250|||WQTI576        
|BEA135|48301: LOVING    TX|82|I|103308|||D|1
MP|3561250|||WQTI576        
|BEA135|48443: TERRELL   TX|984|I|103308|||D|1
MP|3561250|||WQTI576        
|BEA135|48173: GLASSCOCK     TX|1226|I|103308|||D|1
```

**Hence**:

```
res = []             # empty list to store the results
tmp = ''             # empty string for unindented lines
with open(logFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# you may also want to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]

for line in content:
    find_END = line.find('D|1')    # check if line has D|1
    if find_END > 0:
       tmp += line
       res.append(tmp)
       tmp = ''
    else:
     tmp += line

for r in res: print(r)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16077: POWER     ID|7817|I|103306|||D|1
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16011: BINGHAM   ID|45607|I|103306|||D|1
MP|3561042|||WQTI544|BEA148|16005: BANNOCK   ID|82839|I|103306|||D|1
MP|3561250|||WQTI576|BEA135|48301: LOVING    TX|82|I|103308|||D|1
MP|3561250|||WQTI576|BEA135|48443: TERRELL   TX|984|I|103308|||D|1
MP|3561250|||WQTI576|BEA135|48173: GLASSCOCK     TX|1226|I|103308|||D|1
```

Comment: @jezrael: for the same question, when i am trying to use replace function, its not working, Can you tell me what am i doing wrong here ? edited in the question

Comment: @BharatGuda - The best ask answerer, i have no idea.

Comment: @DirtyBit: Can you please let me know why is the replace function not working

Comment: @BharatGuda you're replacing each return and newline with an empty str. That will certainly not work. Since you need to concatenate the lines as I showed in my asnwer.

Comment: @DirtyBit got it!! Ty!

Comment: thanks for sharing the code. On mac I had to rstrip new line from the partial lines, because otherwise the output would still contain them, i.e. file would be unchanged. In else clause: `tmp += line.rstrip()`